# An error in my graduate school application that the application system allowed me to retroactively correct after submission

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, errors-erratum

I applied to several master's programs in the same school system two days ago. While everything else on my application was correct, I only noticed an error in the number of credit hours I had entered in for my undergraduate GPA when, after submission, I read obscure help center information about scaling quarter units to semester form.

Fortunately, the application system allowed me to edit my GPA after submitting my application, so I did so and sent the update to my campuses through the same system.

Now, however, I fear that I may have shot myself in the foot with this correction, and I am wondering if I should notify each admissions office of this change, especially as the application deadlines are two months away at the earliest. Would it be prudent to do so, or should I avoid forcing the issue?

Comment: I don't understand, how would this correction "shoot yourself in the foot"? If the application system lets you make edits, why do you need to do anything else?

Comment: Application season is stressful. But this isn’t something to stress about.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. You are right—I shouldn't worry about it too much, as the application system is somewhat lenient. Perhaps my fear has more to do with what each campus will see when they review my applications, so I want to be as transparent as I can with them about the correction in case it does not show up on their end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do anything else.